# Query result too long to display

Tags: for-loop, sql-server-2005, export

I've a query with a very big xml result. It is a cicle for each customer showing all his invoices in the last six months. The grid show me only the first 100 results. I tryed to store it in a variable and print it but it truncate every circle result. So I think that I need to store variable content in a file. But I don't find a solution to store variable. Only directly the query. But if I store the query I've a separated result. I can also store the var in the clipboard if is better. But I need to understand how. I need this result only one time.
This is the code:

```
DECLARE @anno NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Cliente NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @CodiceCliente NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Fornitore NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @CodiceFornitore NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @datada NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @dataa NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @AZIENDA NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @PIVA NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @INDIRIZZO NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @NOME NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @COGNOME NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @CAP NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @COMUNE NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @PROVINCIA NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @NAZIONE NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @CODFISC NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @DTE NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @DTE = '';
-------INFO DITTA------
SET @AZIENDA = 'XXXX';
SET @PIVA = 'XXXX';
SET @CODFISC = 'XXXX';
SET @INDIRIZZO ='XXXXx';
SET @NOME = 'XXXXX';
SET @COGNOME = 'XXXXX';
SET @CAP = 'XXXXX';
SET @COMUNE = 'XXXXX';
SET @PROVINCIA = 'XX';
SET @NAZIONE = 'XX';
-------------IMPOSTA INTERVALLO DATE-----
SET @datada =  '2017-01-01 00:00:00.000' --- DATEADD(DAY, -150, GETDATE());
SET @dataa = '2017-07-01 00:00:00.000' ---GETDATE();
---- TROVA CLIENTI ---
DECLARE c CURSOR FOR
SELECT DISTINCT
   CODCONTO,
   DSCCONTO1
   --TESTEDOCUMENTI.NUMERODOC
FROM XXX.dbo.TESTEDOCUMENTI 
INNER JOIN XXX.dbo.ANAGRAFICACF
ON CODCLIFOR=CODCONTO
INNER JOIN XXX.dbo.RIGHEDOCUMENTI
ON PROGRESSIVO=IDTESTA AND TOTNETTORIGA <>'0'
LEFT JOIN XXX.dbo.ANAGRAFICAAGENTI
ON CODAGENTE=CODAGENTE1
LEFT JOIN  XXX.dbo.TABPAGAMENTI
ON CODPAGAMENTO = CODICE
WHERE  XXX.dbo.TESTEDOCUMENTI.DOCCHIUSO = '0' AND XXX.dbo.TESTEDOCUMENTI.BLOCCATO = '0' AND (XXX.dbo.TESTEDOCUMENTI.TIPODOC = 'FVC' OR XXX.dbo.TESTEDOCUMENTI.TIPODOC = 'NDC' OR XXX.dbo.TESTEDOCUMENTI.TIPODOC = 'NAC') AND XXX.dbo.TESTEDOCUMENTI.DATADOC BETWEEN @datada AND @dataa
GROUP BY DSCCONTO1,CODCONTO
----DICHIARO LE VARIABILI PER CLIENTE

----PRENDI IL PRIMO CLIENTE E METTILO NELLA VARIABILE----
OPEN c
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @CodiceCliente,@Cliente
--IF @CodiceCliente IS NULL goto finescript;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "DECLARE @anno NVARCHAR(MAX); DECLARE @Cliente NVARCHAR(MAX); DECLARE @CodiceCliente NVARCHAR(MAX); DECLARE @Fornitore NVARCHAR(MAX); DECLARE @CodiceFornitore NVARCHAR(MAX); DECLARE @datada NVARCHAR(MAX); DECLARE @dataa NVARCHAR(MAX); DECLARE @AZIENDA NVARCHAR(MAX); DECLARE @PIVA NVARCHAR(MAX);DECLARE @INDIRIZZO NVARCHAR(MAX); DECLARE @NOME NVARCHAR(MAX);DECLARE @COGNOME NVARCHAR(MAX);DECLARE @CAP NVARCHAR(MAX);DECLARE @COMUNE NVARCHAR(MAX);DECLARE @PROVINCIA NVARCHAR(MAX);DECLARE @NAZIONE NVARCHAR(MAX); DECLARE @CODFISC NVARCHAR(MAX); SELECT DISTINCT @NAZIONE AS "CedentePrestatoreDTE/IdentificativiFiscali/IdFiscaleIVA/IdPaese",@PIVA AS "CedentePrestatoreDTE/IdentificativiFiscali/IdFiscaleIVA/IdCodice",@CODFISC AS "CedentePrestatoreDTE/IdentificativiFiscali/CodiceFiscale",@AZIENDA AS "CedentePrestatoreDTE/AltriDatiIdentificativi/Denominazione",@INDIRIZZO AS "CedentePrestatoreDTE/AltriDatiIdentificativi/Sede/Indirizzo",@CAP AS "CedentePrestatoreDTE/AltriDatiIdentificativi/Sede/CAP",@COMUNE AS "CedentePrestatoreDTE/AltriDatiIdentificativi/Sede/Comune",@PROVINCIA AS "CedentePrestatoreDTE/AltriDatiIdentificativi/Sede/Provincia",@NAZIONE AS "CedentePrestatoreDTE/AltriDatiIdentificativi/Sede/Nazione",ANAGRAFICACF.CODICEISO AS "CessionarioCommittenteDTE/IdentificativiFiscali/IdFiscaleIVA/IdPaese", ANAGRAFICACF.PARTITAIVA AS "CessionarioCommittenteDTE/IdentificativiFiscali/IdFiscaleIVA/IdCodice",ANAGRAFICACF.CODFISCALE AS "CessionarioCommittenteDTE/IdentificativiFiscali/CodiceFiscale",ANAGRAFICACF.DSCCONTO1 AS "CessionarioCommittenteDTE/AltriDatiIdentificativi/Denominazione",ANAGRAFICACF.INDIRIZZO AS "CessionarioCommittenteDTE/AltriDatiIdentificativi/Sede/Indirizzo",ANAGRAFICACF.CAP AS "CessionarioCommittenteDTE/AltriDatiIdentificativi/Sede/CAP",ANAGRAFICACF.LOCALITA AS "CessionarioCommittenteDTE/AltriDatiIdentificativi/Sede/Comune",ANAGRAFICACF.PROVINCIA AS "CessionarioCommittenteDTE/AltriDatiIdentificativi/Sede/Provincia",ANAGRAFICACF.CODICEISO AS "CessionarioCommittenteDTE/AltriDatiIdentificativi/Sede/Nazione",CASE WHEN TESTEDOCUMENTI.TIPODOC = ''FVC'' THEN ''TD01'' WHEN TESTEDOCUMENTI.TIPODOC = ''NDC'' THEN ''TD05'' WHEN TESTEDOCUMENTI.TIPODOC = ''NAC'' THEN ''TD04'' ELSE NULL END AS "CessionarioCommittenteDTE/DatiFatturaBodyDTE/DatiGenerali/TipoDocumento",REPLACE (CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),TESTEDOCUMENTI.DATADOC,111), ''/'',''-'') AS "CessionarioCommittenteDTE/DatiFatturaBodyDTE/DatiGenerali/Data",TESTEDOCUMENTI.NUMERODOC AS "CessionarioCommittenteDTE/DatiFatturaBodyDTE/DatiGenerali/Numero",TOTIMPONIBILE AS "CessionarioCommittenteDTE/DatiFatturaBodyDTE/DatiRiepilogo/ImponibileImporto",TOTIMPOSTA AS "CessionarioCommittenteDTE/DatiFatturaBodyDTE/DatiRiepilogo/DatiIVA/Imposta",ALIQUOTA AS "CessionarioCommittenteDTE/DatiFatturaBodyDTE/DatiRiepilogo/DatiIVA/Aliquota",CODIVA,CASE WHEN TRATTAMENTOIVA.DESCRIZIONE LIKE ''%ART%15%'' THEN ''N1'' WHEN TRATTAMENTOIVA.DESCRIZIONE LIKE ''%N.I.%'' THEN ''N3'' WHEN TRATTAMENTOIVA.DESCRIZIONE LIKE ''ES%'' AND TRATTAMENTOIVA.DESCRIZIONE NOT LIKE ''ESC%'' THEN ''N4'' WHEN TRATTAMENTOIVA.DESCRIZIONE LIKE ''%AUTOFATT%'' THEN ''N6'' WHEN TRATTAMENTOIVA.DESCRIZIONE LIKE ''%40%'' OR TRATTAMENTOIVA.DESCRIZIONE LIKE ''%41%'' OR TRATTAMENTOIVA.DESCRIZIONE LIKE ''%74%'' THEN ''N7'' ELSE '' END AS "CessionarioCommittenteDTE/DatiFatturaBodyDTE/DatiRiepilogo/Natura",100-INDETRAIBILITA AS "CessionarioCommittenteDTE/DatiFatturaBodyDTE/DatiRiepilogo/Detraibile",''I'' AS "CessionarioCommittenteDTE/DatiFatturaBodyDTE/DatiRiepilogo/EsigibilitaIVA",TESTEDOCUMENTI.DATADOC FROM XXX.dbo.TESTEDOCUMENTI INNER JOIN XXX.dbo.ANAGRAFICACF ON CODCLIFOR=CODCONTO LEFT JOIN XXX.dbo.ANAGRAFICAAGENTI ON CODAGENTE=CODAGENTE1 LEFT JOIN  XXX.dbo.TABPAGAMENTI ON CODPAGAMENTO = CODICE INNER JOIN XXX.dbo.RIGHEDOCUMENTI ON RIGHEDOCUMENTI.NUMERODOC = TESTEDOCUMENTI.NUMERODOC INNER JOIN XXX.dbo.TRATTAMENTOIVA ON TRATTAMENTOIVA.CODICE = RIGHEDOCUMENTI.CODIVA WHERE  CODCLIFOR = @CodiceCliente AND XXX.dbo.TESTEDOCUMENTI.DOCCHIUSO = ''0'' AND XXX.dbo.TESTEDOCUMENTI.BLOCCATO = ''0'' AND (XXX.dbo.TESTEDOCUMENTI.TIPODOC = ''FVC'' OR XXX.dbo.TESTEDOCUMENTI.TIPODOC = ''NDC'' OR XXX.dbo.TESTEDOCUMENTI.TIPODOC = ''NAC'')'' AND XXX.dbo.TESTEDOCUMENTI.DATADOC BETWEEN @datada AND @dataa for xml path(''''), elements)" queryout "C:\prova.xml" -x -T'




--PRENDI IL PROSSIMO CLIENTE---
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @CodiceCliente,@Cliente
END
--PULISCI---
CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c
```

and these are the errors:

> SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 102
>
> Error = [Microsoft][SQL Native Client][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '/'.
>
> SQLState = 37000,NativeError = 8180
>
> Error = [Microsoft][SQL Native Client][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bcp queryout` for write results to the file.

For example:

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT TOP * FROM [SampleDB].[dbo].[SampleTable] FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS" queryout "C:\temp\data.xml" -E -c -T -x'
```

Comment: it give me the same error message for lenght : "The query has exceeded the maximum number of result sets that can be displayed in the results grid. Only the first 100 result sets are displayed in the grid."and give me results on sql grid, and don't create the xml file in C.

Comment: in the grid result there are no results but only the help command for bcp.

Comment: All script should be in single line. could you check.

Comment: now it don't see my variables declared, and stop to work. I've a cycle for and all declared variables out of the bcp command.

Comment: I've declared variables again in the bcp, and now I've this 2 errors: - **SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 102 Error = [Microsoft][SQL Native Client][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '/'.** and ** SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 8180 Error = [Microsoft][SQL Native Client][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.** I'll update my code in the first post to let you better understand

Comment: The query is too long, and hard to find the error. Can you convert it to a view and try to use this view instead of all query.